# Running spring boot application behind nginx - missing location prefix when redirect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nginx, redirect

I have spring boot application running on URL: `http://localhost:8080`, with two endpoints:

```
/endpoint1
/login2 - login page for authentication
```

Then I run it behind proxy server - nginx running on port 81. In the nginx configuration when I put something like this:

```
location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;

        }
```

then everything works fine: when I use `http://localhost:81/endpoint1` then I'm redirected to `http://localhost:81/login2`.

However I'd like my nginx application URL to look like `http://localhost:81/my_prefix/login2`. So I've added the prefix to nginx configuration:

```
location /my_prefix/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;

        }
```

But when I try with URL: `http://localhost:81/my_prefix/endpoint1` then I'm redirected to: `http://localhost:81/login2` - without `/my_prefix`.

In my Spring `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration class I have some security configuration with login page for authentication:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/metadata", "/favicon.ico", "/api/**", "/*.css", "/*.js").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()
                            .formLogin().loginPage("/login2").permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
```

Also I have property: `server.use-forward-headers: true`

How can I force Spring MVC to include nginx location prefix (`/my_prefix`) when redirecting to login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a header `X-Forwarded-Prefix: /my_prefix` from your nginx and enable forward headers in Spring Boot application.yaml

```yaml
server.forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
```

See [Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
```

to this:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
```