# Nginx reverse proxy with prefix not working correctly with spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, docker-swarm, nginx-reverse-proxy, prefix

Hi Stackoverflow community !

i am trying to access to my spring boot app behind nginx reverse proxy in docker swarm architecture.
the problem that when i go to http://subdomain.example.com/myapp it redirects me to http://subdomain.example.com/login with 404 no found page instead of the login page on  http://subdomain.example.com/myapp/login

Below my nginx configuration

```
server {
 
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/subdomain.example.com-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/subdomain.example.com-error.log;


    location /myapp/ {

        proxy_pass    http://docker_service_name/;

        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Prefix /myapp;


        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;

        }
}
```

i have added those two lines to my spring boot application.propoerties but keeping redirect to http://subdomain.example.com/login with 404 no found page instead of the login page on  http://subdomain.example.com/myapp/login

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

i tried all those solutions without sucess :

Adding `X-Forwarded-Prefix`

https://library.humio.com/stable/docs/installation/cluster/nginx-reverse-proxy/

Enable forward headers in Spring boot application.properties.

[Running spring boot application behind nginx - missing location prefix when redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328556/running-spring-boot-application-behind-nginx-missing-location-prefix-when-redi)

rewrite URL

https://developpaper.com/nginx-configure-reverse-proxy-to-remove-prefix/

Does someone have a solution for that ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by adding the following line to my `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp
```